# Force separate copy of gnu_inline function with mingw 4.8

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I have a program which I'd like to profile. However, it has some functions declared with attribute gnu_inline. If I try to build the program with -finstrument-functions flag, I get linker errors, for example:

```
#define always_inline __attribute__((always_inline, gnu_inline))
static int inline always_inline f()
{
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = f();

    return i;
}
```

gives me "undefined reference to f()" error.
The problem is that the compiler tries to pass the address of f() to profiling functions, but the function is inlined, so there is no body of function, and no address of f().

I tried to build my program with -fkeep-inline-functions flag, but it apparently has no effect on functions declared with gnu_inline.

Is it possible somehow to force the compiler making a separate copy of f() for linker? Or are such functions unprofileable?

My program uses Qt 5, and these functions are located in Qt headers, so I'd prefer not to alter function declaration, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, the following two options could make your scenario working even though there might be a prettier solution:

> -finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list=file,file,...
>
> Set the list of functions that are excluded from instrumentation (see the description of "-finstrument-functions").  If the file that contains a function definition matches with one
>              of file, then that function is not instrumented.  The match is done on substrings: if the file parameter is a substring of the file name, it is considered to be a match.

```
       For example:

               -finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list=/bits/stl,include/sys

       excludes any inline function defined in files whose pathnames contain "/bits/stl" or "include/sys".

       If, for some reason, you want to include letter ',' in one of sym, write ','. For example, "-finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list=',,tmp'" (note the single quote surrounding the
       option).
```

> -finstrument-functions-exclude-function-list=sym,sym,...
>
> This is similar to "-finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list", but this option sets the list of function names to be excluded from instrumentation. The function name to be matched is its user-visible name, such as "vector blah(const vector &)", not the internal mangled name (e.g., "_Z4blahRSt6vectorIiSaIiEE").  The match is done on substrings: if the sym parameter is a substring of the function name, it is considered to be a match.  For C99 and C++ extended identifiers, the function name must be given in UTF-8, not using universal character names